# How to generate xml from php with mysql group column?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, flex3

I have table (electronics):

```
category     |   product
---------------------------
  Audio         mp3player
  Video           dvd
  Audio         cdplayer
  Video          bluray
  null            lcd
```

I want output:

```
<cat label='Audio'>
      <pro label='mp3player' />
      <pro label='cdplayer' />
</cat>
<cat label='Video'>
      <pro label='dvd' />
      <pro label='bluray' />
</cat>
<pro label='lcd'/>
```

is that posible?

Note: this is for flex 3 tree component data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning xml generated by a while loop to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108284/assigning-xml-generated-by-a-while-loop-to-a-variable)

Comment: no, i think its difference. That link just show 1 product per 1 category; <audio>mp3player</audio><audio>cdplayer</audio>. What I want is just once category.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want by doing the following.  This assumes your table name is catprod and your columns are cat and prod:

```
select concat('<cat label=''',cat,'''>'

    ,GROUP_CONCAT(concat('<prod label=''',prod,''' />') SEPARATOR '')

    ,'</cat>')

from catprod 

where cat is not null

group by cat

UNION

SELECT concat('<pro label=''',prod,'''/>') from catprod where cat is null;
```