# PHP to XML foreach from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Below is the code i am using to create a video list of my movies.  for some reason i cant get the media:content to work.

This is what I have now

```
$xml_output .= "\t<media:content url='" . $row['name'].".m4v" . " type='video/mpg' />\n";
```

Here is the whole thing

```
    $xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"; 
    $xml_output .= "<channel>\n"; 
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<title>Ellucid Movies</title>\n"; 
$xml_output .= "\t\t<link>http://google.com</link>\n"; 
 for($x = 0 ; $x < mysql_num_rows($resultID) ; $x++){ 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultID); 
    $xml_output .= "\t<item>\n"; 
    $xml_output .= "<title>" . $row['name'] .".m4v" . "</title>\n"; 
    $xml_output .= "<link>" . $row['link'] . "</link>\n"; 
$xml_output .= "\t<media:content url='" . $row['name'].".m4v" . " type='video/mpg' />\n";
$xml_output .= "\t</item>\n"; 
} 

$xml_output .= "</channel>"; 

echo $xml_output;
```

when i comment out the media content the xml works as expected... when i add the media it does nothing.

Comment: likely because of missing namespace declaration. also, why are you not using DOM or XMLWriter to create the XML?

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for your reply. How would i declare the namespace?  I have it all the same.. only thing off is the media lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a namespaced element

```
<media:content …
```

but did not declare the namespace anywhere. Add

```
  xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss"
```

to your root element.

Also see my answer to [Assigning xml generated by a while loop to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108284/assigning-xml-generated-by-a-while-loop-to-a-variable/3108408#3108408) on how to use DOM for generating XML with DOM.

Comment: $xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"? xmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss>\n";

Comment: @Dave closing quote is missing